# autocomplete How to avoid duplicate selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using JQuery autocomplete. In which i want to avoid duplicate selection of pre-selected and pre-located (pre fetched) list.

The following script works with currently selected list. But how can I do it with pre-located list which are fetched with `document onload`.

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

**JS**

```
$(document).on('focus','.search',function(){
let type = $(this).data('type');

$(this).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'autocomplete.php',
            dataType: "json",
            method: 'post',
            data: {
               name_startsWith: request.term,
               type: type
            },
            success: function( data ) {
            let selected = [],
               uniques = [],
               choices = [];

            $('tr .search[id^="name_"]').each(function(){
             let value = this.value.trim().toLowerCase();
             if (value && selected.indexOf(value) < 0) {
               selected.push(value);
             }
           });

           data.forEach(item => {
             let value = item.name.trim().toLowerCase();

             if (uniques.indexOf(value) < 0 && selected.indexOf(value) < 0) {
               choices.push({
                 label: item.name,
                 value: item.name,
                 data: item,
                 type: 'name'
               });
               uniques.push(value);
             }

           });

           response(choices);
        }
    });
},
autoFocus: true,
minLength: 1,
select: function( event, ui ) {
    // Strips the 'team_' part, leaving just the number.
    let id_num = $(this).attr('id').substring(5);

    $(this).val(ui.item.value);
    $('#id_' + id_num).val(ui.item.data.id).change();
    $('#marks_' + id_num).val(ui.item.data.marks);
    $(this).attr('data-type', ui.item.type); 
    return false;
},
appendTo: $(this).parent()
});
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="pat_tests">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Marks</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> <input type="number" id="id_1"> </td>
                                    <td><input type="text" id="name_1" class="search" data-type="type"></td>                                    
                                    <td><input type="number" id="marks_1" ></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> <input type="number" id="id_2"> </td>
                                    <td><input type="text" id="name_2" class="search" data-type="type"></td>                                    
                                    <td><input type="number" id="marks_2" ></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td> <input type="number" id="id_3"> </td>
                                    <td><input type="text" id="name_3" class="search" data-type="type"></td>                                    
                                    <td><input type="number" id="marks_3" ></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                        <h2>Pre Selected List of Students</h2>
                        <p class="selected">Mario</p>
                        <p class="selected">Nico"</p>
                        <p class="selected">Mento</p>
```

**PHP**

```
if(!empty($_POST['type'])){
$type = $_POST['type'];
$name = $_POST['name_startsWith'];
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT id, name, marks FROM class where (name LIKE '".$name."%') ");
$query->execute();
$data = array();

$i = 0;
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO:: FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $data[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
    $data[$i]['name'] = $row['name'];
    $data[$i]['marks'] = $row['marks'];
++$i;
}  
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Please post a runable test so we could run he script. remove your ajax call and add a json example that could present the ajax return data.

Comment: Please include a [minimal, complete and reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) example. It would be helpful for both, the asker and the answerer to resolve the problem as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use an array in Js, you can put preselected in it. and then use it to verify if not selected already push in it then you can add to your dom.

so in js you would have something like

```
var selected = [<?= !empty($selected) ? '"'.implode('","', $selected).'"' : '' ?>];
```

above code in firs line of script make an array of empty or already selected if selected is not empty
then you can use it to check if an item is selected or not. also it's better to use `$selected = array_map('strtolower', $selected);` before in php (according to your code)

**EDIT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //in case you have php array of already selected items. remove it if $selected is not provided in php.
    //var selected = [<?= !empty($selected) ? '"'.implode('","', $selected).'"' : '' ?>];

    var selected = []; 
    $(".selected").each(function(index, value){ 
        selected.push($(this).text().trim().toLowerCase()); 
    });

    $(document).on('focus', '.search', function (e) {
        let type = $(this).data('type');
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'your url',
                    dataType: "json",
                    method: 'post',
                    data: {
                        name_startsWith: request.term,
                        type: type
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        let uniques = [],
                            choices = [];
                        data.forEach(function (item) {
                            let value = item.name.trim().toLowerCase();
                            if (uniques.indexOf(value) < 0 && selected.indexOf(value) < 0) {
                                choices.push({
                                    label: item.name,
                                    value: item.name,
                                    data: item,
                                    type: 'name'
                                });
                                uniques.push(value);
                            }
                        });
                        response(choices);
                    }
                });
            },
            autoFocus: true,
            minLength: 1,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                // Strips the 'team_' part, leaving just the number.
                let id_num = $(this).attr('id').substring(5);
                $(this).val(ui.item.value);
                $('#id_' + id_num).val(ui.item.data.id).change();
                $('#marks_' + id_num).val(ui.item.data.marks);
                $(this).attr('data-type', ui.item.type);
                selected.push(ui.item.value.trim().toLowerCase());
                return false;
            },
            appendTo: $(this).parent()
        });
    });
</script>
```

dont wory if you load js as an external file. just make sure define

```
<script>
    var selected = [<?= !empty($selected) ? '"'.implode('","', $selected).'"' : '' ?>];
</script>
```

before it.

Comment: can you please give it in complete form as in my code , And I dont use external js file.

Comment: @Mili complete script provided. for test remove commented lines.

Comment: Actually I am opening different class every time, So pre selected list should be change every time.

Comment: you used html dom to check selected which means every time you open a class, html dom would generate. so you can make selected in php and make selected. unless all actions like opening new class done with ajax. then you should handle changing alreadySelected. (every time you open a class make $selected array and put it in script, use php instead of static array - that was for test)

Comment: And 2nd thing is I am checking 2 pre selected list, first which is fetched with `window.onload` and 2nd list which i am trying to autocomplete currently. As I mentioned above in the question.

Comment: I used one selected variable. for first time pushed preselected and every time you select another value, selected will update. see the change in `select: function ...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193756/discussion-between-saeed-gh-and-mili).

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer:
Because you changed your HTML a solution could be based on:

```
if ($('.selected:contains(' + value + ')').length == 0) {
```

The updated snippet:

```js
$(document).on('focus', '.search', function (e) {
    let type = $(this).data('type');
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.github.com/repositories?since=364',
                dataType: "json",
                method: 'get',
                data: {
                    name_startsWith: request.term,
                    type: type
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    data = data.map((a) => ({name: a.name || ''})).filter((e) => e.name.indexOf('_') == -1);
                    let selected = [],
                            uniques = [],
                            choices = [];
                    $('tr .search[id^="name_"]').each(function () {
                        let value = this.value.trim().toLowerCase();
                        if (value && selected.indexOf(value) < 0) {
                            selected.push(value);
                        }
                    });
                    data.forEach(function (item) {
                        let value = item.name.trim().toLowerCase();
                        if (uniques.indexOf(value) < 0 && selected.indexOf(value) < 0) {
                            if ($('.selected:contains(' + value + ')').length == 0) {
                                choices.push({
                                    label: item.name,
                                    value: item.name,
                                    data: item,
                                    type: 'name'
                                });
                                uniques.push(value);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    response(choices);
                }
            });
        },
        autoFocus: true,
        minLength: 1,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            // Strips the 'team_' part, leaving just the number.
            let id_num = $(this).attr('id').substring(5);
            $(this).val(ui.item.value);
            $('#id_' + id_num).val(ui.item.data.id).change();
            $('#marks_' + id_num).val(ui.item.data.marks);
            $(this).attr('data-type', ui.item.type);
            return false;
        },
        appendTo: $(this).parent()
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="pat_tests">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Marks</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td> <input type="number" id="id_1"> </td>
        <td><input type="text" id="name_1" class="search" data-type="type"></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="marks_1" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <input type="number" id="id_2"> </td>
        <td><input type="text" id="name_2" class="search" data-type="type"></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="marks_2" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <input type="number" id="id_3"> </td>
        <td><input type="text" id="name_3" class="search" data-type="type"></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="marks_3" ></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<h2>Pre Selected List of Students</h2>
<p class="selected">invisible</p>
<p class="selected">tinder</p>
<p class="selected">ike</p>
```

Try to select tinder, just for a test.

Old answer:

First issue: you initialize the autocomplete on every focus event! Please, avoid to initialize it more times.

If I understood correctly, you want  to remove from the autocomplete list elements having a value already contained in one of the  **Pre Selected List of Students**.
If so, you can add, before the **choices.push({** a test:

```
if ($('.selected:text[value="' + item.name + '"]').length == 0) {
```

Full code:

```js
$(document).on('focus', '.search', function (e) {
    let type = $(this).data('type');
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'your url',
                dataType: "json",
                method: 'post',
                data: {
                    name_startsWith: request.term,
                    type: type
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    let selected = [],
                            uniques = [],
                            choices = [];
                    $('tr .search[id^="name_"]').each(function () {
                        let value = this.value.trim().toLowerCase();
                        if (value && selected.indexOf(value) < 0) {
                            selected.push(value);
                        }
                    });
                    data.forEach(function (item) {
                        let value = item.name.trim().toLowerCase();
                        if (uniques.indexOf(value) < 0 && selected.indexOf(value) < 0) {
                            if ($('.selected:text[value="' + item.name + '"]').length == 0) {
                                choices.push({
                                    label: item.name,
                                    value: item.name,
                                    data: item,
                                    type: 'name'
                                });
                                uniques.push(value);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    response(choices);
                }
            });
        },
        autoFocus: true,
        minLength: 1,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            // Strips the 'team_' part, leaving just the number.
            let id_num = $(this).attr('id').substring(5);
            $(this).val(ui.item.value);
            $('#id_' + id_num).val(ui.item.data.id).change();
            $('#marks_' + id_num).val(ui.item.data.marks);
            $(this).attr('data-type', ui.item.type);
            return false;
        },
        appendTo: $(this).parent()
    });
});
```

Comment: It works with this `if ($('.selected').html() !== item.name) {` , But just for 1st selected name. Its not duplicating first name. How can I do it for all.

Comment: Did you try **if ($('.selected:text[value="' + item.name + '"]').length == 0) {** in your loop? Let me know. Thanks

Comment: You may use [:contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/): $('.selected:contains(' + item.name + ')') instead of **.html()**

Comment: Another way can use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/): $('.selected').filter((index, element) => element.textContent == item.name).

Comment: $('.selected').html() returns always the first element content as per [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/). In that case you could, but only could, use [.html( function)](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function).  I suggest the **filter** approach or the **:contains** or my proposed approach. Thanks

Comment: I tried all above methods not working for me. But `if ($('.selected').html() !== item.name) {` works  only for the first selected name. It avoids duplicates for the first name only.

Comment: Can you update the answer with the changed js code?  Your last attempt plus your updated html.  Moreover, can you add a sample of your data on ajax success? Thanks